# How to setup Jenkins Github job on multiple system

Tags: angularjs, git, github, jenkins

I've created a repository on Github using Yoeman, AngularJS, Grunt, npm.
I've configured it on Jenkins, installed Git Plugins, created a Job. It is building properly on every commit of repository.

The issue is when I configure it on other system with same Jenkins configuration and same job configuration, for the same repository, it doesn't work.

For some system it gives error : ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
for others it gives : hudson.plugins.git.GitException

Is it the correct way to configure same Git repository on all the machine and build it or there is some other way I should be doing this job (i.e. master-slave concept)

Answer (score 0):

What for do you want multiple instances of Jenkins? Distributed building? Then use just one Jenkins server and several build nodes. -> master-slave concept